# How to test structure and content of deeply nested objects?

Tags: java

I have objects composed from another objects in several levels and I need to be able to test these objects in the sense that the tested object contains objects with set values at the given level.

When testing, I would like to avoid the procedure:

```
assertSame ("John", order.getUsers().get(0).getName());
assertSame ("Doe", order.getUsers().get(0).getLastName());
```

because there are a lot of levels and the tests would become very complicated and confusing.

**I would like to automate the process and reuse the test code as much as possible.**

I had the idea to create some kind of "template objects" that will have the required / expected data and from these value objects create a final value object in the format of the tested object and compare the two objects in some way.

How would you solve this problem? Is there a procedure or design pattern or test framework for this use case I can use?

Comment: Hm, hard to say without more details. Are you testing on the right level? Could you test that users object independently of the order around it? Reaching deep into the order's customer seems to violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: you can look at Hamcrest library, it provides some matchers which will help you verify things without actually going to that level (to some extent) http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html